# Form based upload to Google cloud storage using Policy document not working

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I tried to follow the example on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#policydocument.

And i am using Java servlet on the Compute Engine and want the user to broswe the servlet page and allow them to direct upload image to the Google Cloud Storage.

But the Google Cloud storage server returned: HTTP 400 Bad Request

```
        // Upload                   
        String googleCloudStorageBucketFullPath = "http://" + m_bucketName + ".storage.googleapis.com";
        String googleAccessIdString = "XXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        String uploadObjectName = "";

        String policyDocumentString =                   
            "{" +
                "\"expiration\": \"2017-06-16T11:11:11Z\"," +
                "\"conditions\": " + 
                "[" +
                    "[\"starts-with\", \"$key\", \"" + uploadObjectName + "\" ]," +
                    "{\"acl\": \"bucket-owner-read\" }," +
                    "{\"bucket\": \"" + m_bucketName + "\"}," +
                    //"{\"success_action_redirect\": \"http://www.example.com/success_notification.html\" }," +
                    "[\"eq\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/jpeg\" ]," +
                    "[\"content-length-range\", 0, 1000000]" +  //1 MB max.
                "]" +
            "}";            

        byte[] signedBase64EncodedPolicyDocumentBytes = null;
        String base64EncodedSignedBase64EncodedPolicyDocumentString = "";

        //Create private key.
        FileInputStream privateKeyInputStream = new FileInputStream(p12PKFullPath);
        try
        {
            String privateKeyPassword = "notasecret";
            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keystore.load(privateKeyInputStream, privateKeyPassword.toCharArray());

            //Sign the policy document using private key.
            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey("privatekey", privateKeyPassword.toCharArray());                           
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            signature.initSign(privateKey);
            signature.update(base64EncodedPolicyDocumentString.getBytes());
            signedBase64EncodedPolicyDocumentBytes = signature.sign();                  
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            out.write("<br>Exception=" + ex.getMessage() + "<br>");             
        }
        finally
        {
            if(privateKeyInputStream != null)
            {
                privateKeyInputStream.close();
                privateKeyInputStream = null;
            }
        }

        base64EncodedSignedBase64EncodedPolicyDocumentString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(signedBase64EncodedPolicyDocumentBytes));

        //Create the html form
        String htmlFormString =
                "<form action=\"" + googleCloudStorageBucketFullPath +"\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" accept-charset=\"UTF-8\">" +
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"key\" value=\"" + uploadObjectName + "\">" +
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"bucket\" value=\"" + m_bucketName + "\">" +
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"Content-Type\" value=\"image/jpeg\">" +
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"GoogleAccessId\" value=\"" + googleAccessIdString + "\">" +
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"acl\" value=\"bucket-owner-read\">" +
                //"<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"success_action_redirect\" value=\"http://www.example.com/success_notification.html\">" +
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"policy\" value=\"" + base64EncodedPolicyDocumentString + "\">" + 
                "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"signature\" value=\"" + base64EncodedSignedBase64EncodedPolicyDocumentString + "\">" +

                "<input name=\"file\" type=\"file\">" +
                "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Upload\">" +
                "</form>";

        out.write("<br>signature=" + base64EncodedSignedBase64EncodedPolicyDocumentString + "<br>");
        out.write(htmlFormString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the problem is that the upload Object Name is missing, but on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object, the object name is not provided, so i don't know why is the sample code don't provide the upload object name and works..